# Snowflake - Select Chunks of Rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to select a chunk of rows based on a query or snowpark API? What I am wanting is for a table with say 1000 rows, I want to select row 1-200 or 201 - 700 etc. There is no row number persisted in the dataset. Does this concept even exist as it does for Oracle of a rownum?

Comment: There is no internal row number, like for Oracle, or temporal one for PostgreSQL. If your data has no natural ordering, put add a new column and use sequence to update it, you now have a stable (albeit random with respect to the data) order.